# What is an efficient algorithm to compare two large lists of data in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, compare

I have two lists of times in nanoseconds.  Each list can have 10^12 elements or more.  My current implementation is to take a subset of both lists, compare the times in that subset using for loops and output correlated times, then take another subset.  For each subset comparison this runs in approx. (m*n) where m is the size of list 1 subset and n is the size of the list 2 subset, which is obviously a bad algorithm.

I also have a clock that is smaller than the total time of my data sets, so there are rollovers in the data to be concerned with at certain times.

List 1 has certain events, and list two has secondary events.  I want to know if the secondary events happen within a certain time from the primary events.  There is also a lot of noise, so I need to create a histogram of correlated times and look for a time where there is a statistically significant signal.

I would like to know if there is a known efficient algorithm that can be used in C++ from any open source library, or an efficient algorithm that I can implement, to search the times of both lists, and output the items that fall within the window.

Here is an example of the brute force function:

```
int correlate_lists( int window )
{
  for( int i = 0 ; i < list1.size() ; i++ )
  {  
    for( int j = 0 ; j < list2.size() ; j++ )
    {
      if( list2[j].time() > list1[i].time() &&  (list2[j].time() - list1[j].time()) < window )
      {
        printf("Time: %d\n, list2[j].time() - list[1].time() );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Compare based on what criteria? Only this in your example code?

Comment: Seems like sorting the two lists would be required to make it efficient.

Comment: yes, I am only comparing what is above in the code example.

Comment: Did you intend for the test to be `(list2[j].time() - list1[j].time()) < window` instead of `list2[j].time() < window`?

Comment: For one, you could change the counters from post increment to pre-increment, should be a *little* faster. Then it looks like this task will lend itself to parallelization well, you should get a nice performance boost. For an actual specialized algorithm for this workload - I don't know, perhaps someone more qualified can propose one.

Comment: @ddriver Pre-increment? Really? **Come on...**

Comment: The input is two lists of times stored as doubles, and an integer to define the window to search in.  The lists have rollovers approx. every 90 minutes, so for any sorting algorithms I have to find some way to keep the times from being combined.  Also the lists aren't synchronized very well so the start time of each list can be off by up to 2 seconds.

Comment: Sorry, typo in the code above, it is supposed to be (list2[j].time() - list1[j].time()) < window.

Comment: I had been thinking of trying to put the data sets into a tree and labelling each with a second variable like L1 and L2 and doing some sort of tree traversal to see if there are elements next to each other from each list, then checking to see if they are in the window.  I haven't done much with actually coding trees so I'm not familiar with any good libraries for doing that, or if it would be a good implementation.

Comment: Up to 10^12 elements or more... As the times are in nanoseconds, I assume you need at least 64 bit data type to store them. Do you really possess 16TB of RAM to store that? Or are your lists data structures from something like STXXL and are stored on an external drive?

Comment: I am reading in the data from files.  One month of files has 5,184,000,000 events, which is list 1.  I guess 10^11 would be a tighter upper bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your two lists are sorted by time, you can walk through the lists efficiently:

```
  for( int i = 0, j = 0 ; i < list1.size() ; ++i )
  {  
    while( j < list2.size() && list2[j].time() <= list1[i].time() ) 
    {
      ++j;
    }

    int k = j;

    while( k < list2.size() && list2[k].time() < list1[i].time() + window) 
    {
      printf("Time: %d\n, list2[k].time() - list1[i].time() );
      ++k;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Since those are supposedly time stamp inputs, I think the order is important.

Comment: @ddriver: Yes, in fact they may already be sorted by time for that reason.

Comment: But only if they are actual time stamps and not intervals between timestamps. The latter case it would be impractical to sort, because you don't know what is what.

Comment: @ddriver: The comments by the OP have clarified that they are lists of times and not intervals.

Comment: I'll give this implementation a try and see if it improves my time.  I apologize for not clarifying very well what I meant by times in my question, the times are timestamps in nanoseconds.  With this version I still have to handle rollovers, but it may be fast enough that I can do subsets of times between rollovers.

Comment: @Cerekay: To handle rollovers, all you should really have to do is implement a a comparison function that considers rollovers, i.e. for unsigned values `less(a,b) = (b-a) < MAX/2)`

Answer (score 0):

If the lists are sorted, surely you can use a binary search to find the "window" position?

Comment: I had considered a binary search tree, but I am not familiar with any libraries that allow me to quickly use an already implemented one.

Comment: @Cerekay: I was thinking of [std::binary_search](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/)